# Perl and shell script in redhat

Tags: linux, bash, perl, jenkins

I am pretty new to Perl, Linux and shell scripts.  Can anybody let me know what exactly is this piece of script doing? I have searched through internet and couldn't find answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +xe

if [ x"$Link_A" == "x" ] ; then
echo "Link_A parameter not set, DOESNOT execute FUNCTION"
else
cp -f ~/cached-resources/www.github.com/file1/executables/JenkinsScripts/jenkins_feed.pl ./jenkins_feed.pl
perl jenkins_feed.pl $JENKINS_HOME/feed_config.ini $Link_A
fi
```

Any help is appreciated.

I added the source code in Perl and edited the shell parameter names too.
What do I need to change or append or place in system path to make this Perl file run.

Source code: https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another explanation:

```
#!/bin/bash

# enable debug
set +xe 

# this is an old school way to check for an empty variable    
# modern shells can use [[ $foo == "" ]] to do this
if [ x"$Link_A" == "x" ] ; then

    # a normal error message for when the variable is not set
    echo "Link_A parameter not set, DOESNOT execute FUNCTION"
else # the variable has a value so we can use it...

    # copy this file to the current directory
    cp -f ~/cached-resources/www.github.com/file1/executables/JenkinsScripts/jenkins_feed.pl ./jenkins_feed.pl

    # run the script in perl with arguments that include variable
    # substitution and some fixed text
    perl jenkins_feed.pl $JENKINS_HOME/feed_bts.ini $Link_A
fi
```

I also reformatted the script so the inner parts of the conditional are indented.

## bonus questions from comments

> 1. Is Link_A a file ?

`Link-A` is a variable.  A variable could point to a file or directory, but it isn't clear what the variable would contain in this case.  Examining the `perl` script would be necessary to answer this definitively.

> 2. what does feed_bts.ini means do i need to create a file like this explicitly if not present?

I'd guess the perl script is expecting a file name as its first argument.  The shell script provides this and it expects the `feed_bts.ini` file to be in the `$JENKINS_HOME` (another variable) directory.

> 3. Do I need to keep the jenkins_feed.pl and feed_bts.ini in same directory to run the script?

The `jenkins_feed.pl` ends up in the same directory as the shell script because of the `cp`.  It starts as `~/cached-resources/www.github.com/file1/executables/JenkinsScripts/jenkins_feed.pl`.  Note that `~` would the home directory of the user the script runs as.

> 4. from which path is the perl script executing

This would probably be using whatever the stock perl installed with your distro is.  Technically the shell will look through all of the directories in your `$PATH` until it finds it or runs out of directories.

## perl script analysis

- The second argument `$Link_A` has three pieces of information in it.  On https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L17 this gets split into three variables: `$Link_A,$skey,$priority`.

  1. The first part of this gets stuffed back into the same-named variable which only gets used at https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L90.  That looks like it is just arbitrary text that shows up in a particular place in the description (`$desc`) which ends up in the Jenkins XML field `IV_DESCRIPTION`.
  2. The `$skey` goes into the Jenkins XML field `IV_EVENT_KEY`.  There's a default value for this just in case at https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L129.
  3. The `$priority` goes into the Jenkins XML field `IV_PRIORITY`.
- I didn't find anything convenient to define what those fields are doing.  They are part of a SOAP call to "`feed_issue_CREATION`".
- The first argument to the script looks like a config file.

  1. https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L14 reads the first argument from the command line.  If it is missing you go to the `usage` subroutine.
  2. Then https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L19 checks to make sure it exists and it is a file.  If not go to the `usage` subroutine again.
  3. https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L49 calls the `readopeninc` subroutine with the config file name as the argument.
  4. https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L287 defines the `readopeninc` subroutine which seems to do a few things.  It ignores lines that start with a `#` as the absolute first character.  It strips any leading and trailing white space.  Then it assumes you're got variable assignments like the shell: `VAR_NAME=SOME_VALUE`
  5. After that the it seems to use the values in there as jobs that need to be updated or closed.
- based on https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L115 it looks like the `$inclog` aka `feed_INC.txt` is in the same format somehow.
- based on https://github.com/rebeccaus/perl/blob/master/feed.pl#L80 it is looking for the files to be in the current directory.

Comment: thanks for such a nice explanation.
I have few questions here. 1. Is Link_A a file ?    2. what does feed_bts.ini means do i need to create a file like this explicitly if not present?    
     3. Do I need to keep the jenkins_feed.pl and feed_bts.ini in same directory to run the script?
     4. from which path is the perl script executing?

Comment: Thank you very much :-) @ chicks

Comment: Can you help me with the perl script if Ok for you as I am not able to put the things in proper way. It would be great :-)

Comment: Please edit the initial question to include the source code from the script and whatever specific questions you have about it.

Comment: I have added the source code repo can you please help here

Comment: I think I've done a passable job at interpreting the script.  Have I covered what you hoped for?

Comment: Great @chicks Thank you very much for so detailed explanation, appreciate a lot.
So I would need a config file hardcoded the info in it and the perl script to run with the shell

Answer (score 0):

See below to understand line by line use of your script -

```
#!/bin/bash #### Used to set the type of script "bash"
set +xe  #### Used to execute the script in debug mode (set +x) and e is used to receive the input from terminal

if [ x"$Link_A" == "x" ] ; then    ##### condition check if x appending something is equal to x means no value in variable LinK_A
echo "Link_A parameter not set, DOESNOT execute FUNCTION"   ##### print this line if above condition is true
else  ###### if above condition is not true do below operation
cp -f ~/cached-resources/www.github.com/file1/executables/JenkinsScripts/jenkins_feed.pl ./jenkins_feed.pl
#####above line copy the file jenkis_feed.pl from specified directory to current dir forcefully
perl jenkins_feed.pl $JENKINS_HOME/feed_bts.ini $Link_A #### execute jenkil program which take two input parameter
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @ vipin kumar 
two questions here
is Link_A a kind of file ?
what is feed_bts.ini ? is that a file what kind of file is it , with regards to the content?